# why is loading image from network using uri gives 'Failed host lookup' in flutter?

Tags: flutter, android-emulator

when i try to load image from network error using URL in android emulator .

```
Image.network('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1547721064-da6cfb341d50',
height=350)
```

the following error appears

```
The following SocketException was thrown resolving an image codec:
Failed host lookup: 'images.unsplash.com' (OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7)
```

Comment: there is also small change needed `height:350` & can you try with `flutter clean` and rebuild the app

Comment: are you behind a proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the required permissions? See https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/networking

For me in a simple PoC this works fine.
If you did add permissions, it is likely an issue with your network, the device might simply not have a connection.